# An iterator returning all possible permutations of a list in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics, iterator

I have this class that iterates over all permutations of an input list:

**`PermutationIterable.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * This class implements an {@code Iterable} returning all possible permutations 
 * of a list.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 14, 2016) :*
 */
public class PermutationIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

    final List<T> allElements = new ArrayList<>();

    public PermutationIterable(List<T> allElements) {
        this.allElements.addAll(allElements);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return new PermutationIterator<>(allElements);
    }

    private static final class PermutationIterator<T> 
    implements Iterator<List<T>> {

        private List<T> nextPermutation;
        private final List<T> allElements = new ArrayList<>();
        private int[] indices;

        PermutationIterator(List<T> allElements) {
            if (allElements.isEmpty()) {
                nextPermutation = null;
                return;
            }

            this.allElements.addAll(allElements);
            this.indices = new int[allElements.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i) {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            nextPermutation = new ArrayList<>(this.allElements);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextPermutation != null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<T> next() {
            if (nextPermutation == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No permutations left.");
            }

            List<T> ret = nextPermutation;
            generateNextPermutation();
            return ret;
        }

        private void generateNextPermutation() {
            int i = indices.length - 2;

            while (i >= 0 && indices[i] > indices[i + 1]) {
                --i;
            }

            if (i == -1) {
                // No more new permutations.
                nextPermutation = null;
                return;
            }

            int j = i + 1;
            int min = indices[j];
            int minIndex = j;

            while (j < indices.length) {
                if (indices[i] < indices[j] && indices[j] < min) {
                    min = indices[j];
                    minIndex = j;
                }

                ++j;
            }

            swap(indices, i, minIndex);

            ++i;
            j = indices.length - 1;

            while (i < j) {
                swap(indices, i++, j--);
            }

            loadPermutation();
        }

        private void loadPermutation() {
            List<T> newPermutation = new ArrayList<>(indices.length);

            for (int i : indices) {
                newPermutation.add(allElements.get(i));
            }

            this.nextPermutation = newPermutation;
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] array, int a, int b) {
        int tmp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = tmp;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        List<String> alphabet = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
        int row = 1;

        for (List<String> permutation : new PermutationIterable<>(alphabet)) {
            System.out.printf("%2d: %s\n", row++, permutation);
        }
    }
}
```

What can I improve here? Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: Why have an `Iterable` of the permutations and not have a method that simply generates them all?

Comment: I was encouraged to use the iterator pattern. Also, if a client programmer might wish to halt generating the permutations at some point, the approach you are suggesting might waste **a lot** of computation.

Comment: @Tunaki generating all would imply storing all in memory. This might not even be possible. Using an iterator you can drastically reduce the memory use.

Comment: This is true but when you start generating permutations, you generally want all of them (because it means you're brute forcing something). And when you don't want all of them, there's probably another approach to the problem that doesn't require permutation to begin with. Just out of curiosity, what is the use-case of this iterator? Or is it an exercise to learn?

Comment: Well, it's a good question, since I did not find any except brute-forcing the TSP.  Any idea where this might be of use?

Comment: @coderodde TSP as in Travelling Salesman Problem?

Comment: Yes, that very same.

Comment: @coderodde Well, typically for this problem, brute-force (which is of complexity O(n!)) becomes impractical very quick and there are other alternatives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Computing_a_solution

Comment: Yeah, I know. Genetic algorithms; ant-colony; etc.

Comment: Nice. Thought about ListIterator/Spliterator instead - not really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks good. It's a really challenging task. This is because you have to "flatten" an algorithm with recursive nature. Furthermore you have to break it apart into single steps and to be able to resume at the last step made.

So there are little things that I would change:

1. I like separated classes instead of inner classes they are more handy in testing
2. I would have separated the algorithm in "generateNextPermutation()" in an additional class.
3. I would follow the recursive nature of the problem and build a recursive structure. This is a slightly different approach.
4. I do not exactly know how the algorithm should behave if you provide an empty list. I assume that you will have one permutation as result. So I adapted your algorithm to work with an empty array of indices.

You see that our solutions do not differ in structure. Only the algorithm to generate a new permutation is extracted in a class and reformulated.

I unpacked this riddle (I somehow liked this riddle) and I want to provide a solution that can use either your algorithm or mine. But finally they converged against the same interface. I expected that as I know there is only one structure that fits the problem best. We may not have found it but both solutions have a "meeting" where the structure is mostly the same AND the things that may be different can work under the same abstraction. Sure, most structure was provided by the interfaces "Iterable" and "Iterator" but I found it interesting how the algorithms are interchangeable.

So first of all the interface for our algorithms:

```
public interface PermutationResolver<T> {

    List<T> resolvePermutation(List<T> base);

    boolean nextStep();

}
```

Your algorithm:

```
public class IndicesWalker<T> implements PermutationResolver<T> {

    private int[] indices;

    public IndicesWalker(int elements) {
        indices = new int[elements];
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i) {
            indices[i] = i;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextStep() {

        if (indices.length == 0) return false;

        int i = indices.length - 2;

        while (i >= 0 && indices[i] > indices[i + 1]) {
            --i;
        }

        if (i == -1) {
            // No more new permutations.
            return false;
        }

        int j = i + 1;
        int min = indices[j];
        int minIndex = j;

        while (j < indices.length) {
            if (indices[i] < indices[j] && indices[j] < min) {
                min = indices[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }

            ++j;
        }

        swap(indices, i, minIndex);

        ++i;
        j = indices.length - 1;

        while (i < j) {
            swap(indices, i++, j--);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> resolvePermutation(List<T> base) {

        List<T> newPermutation = new ArrayList<>(indices.length);

        for (int i : indices) {
            newPermutation.add(base.get(i));
        }

        return newPermutation;
    }

    private void swap(int[] array, int a, int b) {
        int tmp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = tmp;
    }

}
```

Mine:

```
public class RecursiveCounter<T> implements PermutationResolver<T> {

    private int i;
    private int max;
    private RecursiveCounter<T> nextState;

    public RecursiveCounter(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        this.i = 0;
        if (this.max > 1) {
            nextState = new RecursiveCounter<T>(max - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextStep() {

        boolean wasIncremented = true;

        if (nextState != null) {
            if (!nextState.nextStep()) {
                if (this.i == this.max - 1) {
                    this.i = 0;
                    wasIncremented = false;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            wasIncremented = false;
        }

        return wasIncremented;
    }


    private int getI(int level) {
        if (level == 0) {
            return this.i;
        } else {
            return nextState.getI(level - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> resolvePermutation(List<T> base) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<T> work = new ArrayList<>(base);
        for(int i = 0; i < base.size(); i++) {
            result.add(work.remove(getI(i)));
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

The iterator:

```
public class PermutationIterator<T> implements Iterator<List<T>>  {

    private List<T> base;

    private PermutationResolver<T> permutationResolver;
    private List<T> next;

    public PermutationIterator(List<T> base, PermutationResolver<T> resolver) {
        this.base = base;
        this.next = new ArrayList<>(base);
        this.permutationResolver = resolver;
    }

    private List<T> generateNextPermutation(boolean isLast) {

        List<T> result = null;

        if (!isLast) {
            result = getPermutationResolver().resolvePermutation(base);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> next() {

        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        List<T> current = next;

        this.next = generateNextPermutation(!getPermutationResolver().nextStep());

        return current;
    }


    private PermutationResolver<T> getPermutationResolver() {
        return permutationResolver;
    }

}
```

The iterable:

```
public class PermutationIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

    private List<T> base;
    private PermutationResolver<T> resolver;

    public PermutationIterable(List<T> base, PermutationResolver<T> resolver) {
        super();
        this.base = base;
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return new PermutationIterator<T>(base, resolver);
    }

}
```

Code in action with both algorithms:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> base = Arrays.asList();

        PermutationIterable<String> permutationIterable1 = new PermutationIterable<String>(base, new IndicesWalker<String>(base.size()));

        for (List<String> permutation : permutationIterable1) {
            System.out.println(permutation);
        }

        PermutationIterable<String> permutationIterable2 = new PermutationIterable<String>(base, new RecursiveCounter<String>(base.size()));

        for (List<String> permutation : permutationIterable2) {
            System.out.println(permutation);
        }

    }

}
```